Reports on action plan object
Is it possible to create reports on action plan object? I am able to create reports on Task object but I do not see action plans as an object. Is it possible by creating a custom report type?

Are you using a particular industry Cloud like Health Cloud or Financial Services Cloud?  Since the ActionPlan object is available only to certain industry Clouds, you should check that your user has the correct permission set license and permission set assignments.

Check if this may be helpful - https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gddl2UAB/report-on-action-plan-items

I do have Financial Services Cloud. Action plans are enabled. Is there any specific setting to activate it for reports? I am not able to report on them. eg: like accounts with action plans.

You may need to create a Custom Report Type to report on them. Not all of the industries cloud objects are available using standard report types. Check out the Create a Custom Report Type help article if you aren't sure how to do that.

Ok that seems to have worked.

So what worked is that I had to create a custom report type on the Account object and then choose Action Plans as the secondary or related object. This way I was able to create reports on Accounts with Action Plan assigned.

Could you see the Action Plan as an available object to Account when creating the Custom Report Type. When I try to add a related Object, action plans does not show in the list. I have all available permissions.
